# Android / SQLite: How to ignore PHONEBOOK collation?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contacts, collation

I want to migrate my contacts from my old android phone to my noew android phone.
I do it on my computer with an SQL editor, called SQLite Expert Personal 5.4

`DELETE FROM [raw_contacts]` says:
No such collation sequence: PHONEBOOK

I created a sample contact on my new phone to identify what is what in the database. And i want to delete it before inserting the real datas. And of course, this is the same message on INSERT.

What could be the solution?

- Create a PHONEBOOK collation on my PC-application? *How?*
- Make it ignore collations? *How?*
- Map the PHONEBOOK collation to an existing collation in my PC-application? *How?*
- Change the PHONEBOOK collation to BINARY? It works actually, erros message does not come. But will this couse any problems later?

Comment: Why?  Contacts synced to a google account automatically sync down.  If you want it to be more anonymous, create a new google account, sync it up, then sync it down.  Then delete it on both devices.

Comment: What is on the internet (or at Google) once, it stays there.

Comment: So make a throw away.  It's a lot easier than trying to reverse engineer their storage format.  Or if you need to do this, rather than using their SQL file directly, write an app that writes the data to a CSV, and another that parses the CSV and writes new contacts.  There's apis for adding contacts.  Reverse engineering the SQL format is overly hard and fragile.

Comment: search google play for contacts backup and restore apps that will do this for you, don't mess with the sql directly as each android version works a bit differently with the Contacts DB